# React routing on click event is not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am doing routing on button click event

```
  redirect(){

       return <Redirect to='/chat' />;

    }
```

Its not working.

my home page- base component:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

  render() {

    const { value } = this.state;

    return (


        <Router>

          <div>
             <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/notify" component={Notify} />
            <Route path="/chat" component={Chat}/>
</Switch>

          </div>
          <footer className="foot">
            <BottomNavigation className="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-bottom navbar-fixed-bottom" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} className={this.props.root}>

                <div className="navi">
                  <Link   to="/"> <BottomNavigationAction label="Home" value="Home" icon={<HomeIcon />} /></Link>
                </div>
                <div  className="navi">
                <Link to="/notify"><BottomNavigationAction label="Notification" value="Notification" icon={<NotifyIcon />} /></Link>
                </div>
                <div className="navi">
                <Link to="/chat"> <BottomNavigationAction label="Listen" value="Listen" icon={<LocationOnIcon />} /></Link>
                </div>

            </BottomNavigation>
          </footer>
```

From my child component I have to redirect to another component,
here is my child component:

```
  <IconButton className={this.props.iconButton} aria-label="Search" onClick={this.redirect}>
        <SearchIcon />
      </IconButton>

redirect(){

       return <Redirect to='/chat' />;

    }
```

So but I am not getting any console error too.

Comment: its because `Redirect` is a ui element, you have to render that and onClick is an event handler it will not render anything, it will simply execute the body of the handler function. To solve your issue, use `this.props.history.push('/chat')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<Redirect />` is a component. So, you should use it like this.

```
class App extends React.Component{
  state = { 
    isRedirect: false,
  }

  redirect = () => {
    this.setState({ isRedirect: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onclick={this.redirect}> Redirect</button>

        {this.state.isRedirect ? <Redirect to="/" /> : null }
      </>
    ) 
  }

}
```

**OR**

You can use **history API**

but you should add `withRouter()`

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.props.history.push('/')}}>Redirect</button>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: I chose the history API method its working

Comment: @SridharPaiya I agree, `history API` is more recommendable